# Instagram api if account is business account nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, get, axios, instagram

So in my node app i make an axios.get request to this url:https://www.instagram.com/nodejs.testing/?__a=1

And i get an html response from a login browser.

But in my browser i get json data and i dont have to login again as i have already logged in.

Why nodejs then go to login when i am already login.

Anyone know how to fix or an alternative way to check if an account username is a business account?